# How to group list of start times by a category?

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, window-functions

I have a list people and when they started occupied various rooms in the building. Like so:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RoomAssignments') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #RoomAssignments;
CREATE TABLE #RoomAssignments (
  PersonID smallint,
  FloorNum tinyint,
  Room varchar(5),
  EnterTime datetime
);
INSERT INTO #RoomAssignments (PersonID, FloorNum, Room, EnterTime) VALUES
  (24601, 23, 'S', CONVERT(datetime,'2015-02-27 07:42:03.287', 121)),
  (24601, 16, 'F', CONVERT(datetime,'2015-02-27 11:29:59.497', 121)),
  (24601, 12, 'B', CONVERT(datetime,'2015-03-03 14:38:03.243', 121)),
  (24601, 41, 'E', CONVERT(datetime,'2015-03-03 21:03:05.007', 121)),
  (24601, 12, 'B', CONVERT(datetime,'2015-03-05 10:17:36.773', 121)),
  (24601, 15, 'S', CONVERT(datetime,'2015-03-05 12:19:40.573', 121)),
  (24601, 15, 'P', CONVERT(datetime,'2015-03-06 21:51:20.430', 121)),
  (24601, 15, 'L', CONVERT(datetime,'2015-03-09 10:25:00.127', 121)),
  (24601, 16, 'A', CONVERT(datetime,'2015-03-10 17:19:30.550', 121))
;
SELECT * FROM #RoomAssignments
ORDER BY Personid, EnterTime;
/********* #RoomAssignments: ********************
Person FloorNum  Room  EnterTime
------ --------- ----- ------------------------
24601  23        S     2015-02-27 07:42:03.287
24601  16        F     2015-02-27 11:29:59.497
24601  12        B     2015-03-03 14:38:03.243
24601  41        E     2015-03-03 21:03:05.007
24601  12        B     2015-03-05 10:17:36.773
24601  15        S     2015-03-05 12:19:40.573
24601  15        P     2015-03-06 21:51:20.430
24601  15        L     2015-03-09 10:25:00.127
24601  16        A     2015-03-10 17:19:30.550
************************************************/
```

I'd like to get that data grouped by person/floor with the next beginning timestamp becoming the end timestamp of the previous row.  Like this:

```
/********* Desired Output: ******************************************
id     FloorNum  FromTime                 ToTime
------ --------- ------------------------ ------------------------
24601  23        2015-02-27 07:42:03.287  2015-02-27 11:29:59.497
24601  16        2015-02-27 11:29:59.497  2015-03-03 14:38:03.243
24601  12        2015-03-03 14:38:03.243  2015-03-03 21:03:05.007
24601  41        2015-03-03 21:03:05.007  2015-03-05 10:17:36.773
24601  12        2015-03-05 10:17:36.773  2015-03-05 12:19:40.573
24601  15        2015-03-05 12:19:40.573  2015-03-10 17:19:30.550
24601  16        2015-03-10 17:19:30.550  NULL
********************************************************************/
```

I've tried to come up with various uses of window functions to solve this in a set-based manner, but I can't seem to find a way to group consecutive entries on the same floor together while separating the non-consecutive ones.

Comment: You aren't really grouping here, are you? You are just looking at the next record's ToTime (regardless of which floor or room or individual). If that is all you want, then just use Lead() windowing function. Or is your example flawed?

Comment: @ChrisWoods They are looking for the next row, right, but the next row that has a different floor number.

Comment: Gotcha, I figured he was looking for when a room was being used (start to end). I see now that he is looking for where a person was (start to end) throughout the day.

Comment: i also can't do a simple MIN/MAX grouped by Person,Floor -- because that wouldn't handle non-consecutive occurrences of the same floor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the newly added `LAG()` and `LEAD()` functions makes it look easy:

```
WITH a AS
    ( SELECT PersonID, FloorNum, EnterTime,
             PrevFloorNum = LAG(FloorNum) OVER
                                (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY EnterTime)
      FROM RoomAssignments
    ) 
SELECT PersonID, FloorNum,
       FromTime = EnterTime,
       ToTime = LEAD(EnterTime) OVER 
                    (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY EnterTime)
FROM a
WHERE PrevFloorNum <> FloorNum OR PrevFloorNum IS NULL 
ORDER BY PersonID, FromTime ;
```

Test in [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f610a/2)

Comment: exactly my issue

Comment: I thought it again and I think that null is the correct thing to show in that case, too. There is no need to change the query. So, please test and tell me if this answers your problem.